# Exception: No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of String(),String,boolean)'.- Delegate function

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have got this exception while calling the delegate function `isInventoryBook`. The error message says, `No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of String(),String,Boolean)'`.

My Code is mentioned below:

```
If isInventoryBook(InvBooksArr, "DCLL.") Then
    If chk.Value = True Then
        chk.Value = False
    Else
        chk.Value = True
    End If
End If
```

- Calling Delegate Function :

```
Dim isInventoryBook = Function(arr As String(), temp As String) As Boolean
                                Return arr.Contains(temp)
                            End Function
```

Comment: initially it was calling fine but all of sudden throwing this Exception `No default member found for type 'VB$AnonymousDelegate_0(Of String(),String,Boolean).`

Comment: You should declare the function delegate explicitly: `Dim isInventoryBook As Func(Of String(), String, Boolean) = Function(...)`. Is `isInventoryBook` declared as a local variable?

Comment: @Jimi no `isInventoryBook` is not a local variable.

Comment: So, is it an instance Field? Part of some other class? Anyway, declare the delegate explicitly otherwise it's inferred as `Object`.

Comment: Now getting [this](https://pasteboard.co/JMjWLli.png) error. which states nested func does not have same signature as delegate

Comment: That's not what I wrote. The delegate is missing a return Type. The full declaration is `dim isInventoryBook As Func(Of String(), String, Boolean) = Function(arr As String(), temp As String) As Boolean Return arr.Contains(temp) End Function`. You should really set `Option Strict On`

Comment: @Jimi Actually I didn't get your point. can you give me the code snippet which you are talking about... where to write `Strinct on`

Comment: @Jimi Bro, Thank alot for guidance.

Comment: @Jimi where to write `Option Strict On`

Answer (score 1):

Since the function delegate is not declared as a Local Variable but as an Instance Field, the Type Inference works in a different way.

This is described in the Visual Basic Language documentation:

[Local Type Inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/variables/local-type-inference):

> Local type inference applies at procedure level. It cannot be used to
> declare variables at module level (within a class, structure, module,
> or interface but not within a procedure or block)

Declared as a Field:

```
' This is inferred as Object
Public Class SomeClass
    Private isInventoryBook = 
        Function(arr As String(), temp As String) As Boolean
            Return arr.Contains(temp)
        End Function
' [...]
End Class
```

the function delegate is then inferred as `Object`, no matter whether [Option Infer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement) is `On` or `Off`.

If the delegate is instead declared at procedure level and `Option Infer` is `On`, the delegate and its return Type are inferred as one might expect.

```
Private Sub SomeMethod()
    
   ' This is inferred as Function(Of String(), String, Boolean) 
    Dim isInventoryBook =
    Function(arr As String(), temp As String) As Boolean
        Return arr.Contains(temp)
    End Function

    ' [...]       
    If isInventoryBook(someArray, "SomeValue") Then
        ' [...]
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the delegate is declared as a Field, provide the full declaration:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Private isInventoryBook As Func(Of String(), String, Boolean) =
        Function(arr As String(), temp As String) As Boolean 
             Return arr.Contains(temp) 
        End Function
' [...]
End Class
```

---

Setting [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) to `On` would notify that this Field declaration is not allowed and also clearly show that the delegate is treated as an `Object` Type, not a Function.

`Option Infer` and `Option Strict` can be pre-set in different ways:

- as default in the Visual Studio Option tool:
  `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solution -> VB Defaults`
- at Project Level:
  `Project -> Properties -> Compile`
- you can also set the Options at Class / Module level (it can be useful in case you don't want to refactor your entire Project if you have used `Option Strict Off` as default setting):
  Add each `Option` on top of the file